# How to add values to row?

Tags: python, pandas

**How to add values to row** :

1. I created one column in data frame and assign value to 0.
2. Written logic to update these now column value, but not reflecting.

**Input:**

```
>>> parafix_df = main_df[["line_width", "para_num", "bbox" ]]
>>> parafix_df
   line_width para_num                             bbox
0     238.546      NaN  (50.0, 579.3, 288.546, 598.022)
1         318        1    (64.0, 564.9, 382.0, 583.622)
2         332        2    (50.0, 550.5, 382.0, 569.222)
3         332        2    (50.0, 536.1, 382.0, 554.822)
4     328.977        2  (50.0, 521.7, 378.977, 540.422)
5         318        3    (64.0, 507.3, 382.0, 526.022)
6         332        3    (50.0, 492.9, 382.0, 511.622)
7         332        3    (50.0, 478.5, 382.0, 497.222)
8         332        3    (50.0, 464.1, 382.0, 482.822)
9         332        3    (50.0, 449.7, 382.0, 468.422)
10      59.04        3   (50.0, 435.3, 109.04, 454.022)
11    304.007        4  (64.0, 420.9, 368.007, 439.622)
12        318        5    (64.0, 406.5, 382.0, 425.222)
13        332        5    (50.0, 392.1, 382.0, 410.822)
14        332        5    (50.0, 377.7, 382.0, 396.422)
15        332        5    (50.0, 363.3, 382.0, 382.022)
16     43.252        5   (50.0, 348.9, 93.252, 367.622)
17        318        6    (64.0, 334.5, 382.0, 353.222)
18        332        6    (50.0, 320.1, 382.0, 338.822)
19        332        6    (50.0, 305.7, 382.0, 324.422)
20        332        6    (50.0, 291.3, 382.0, 310.022)
21        332        6    (50.0, 276.9, 382.0, 295.622)
22     317.02        6   (50.0, 262.5, 367.02, 281.222)
23        318        7    (64.0, 248.1, 382.0, 266.822)
24        332        7    (50.0, 233.7, 382.0, 252.422)
25     47.014        7   (50.0, 219.3, 97.014, 238.022)
26        318        8    (64.0, 204.9, 382.0, 223.622)
27    316.723        8  (50.0, 190.5, 366.723, 209.222)
28        318        9    (64.0, 176.1, 382.0, 194.822)
29    326.766        9  (50.0, 161.7, 376.766, 180.422)
30        318       10    (64.0, 147.3, 382.0, 166.022)
31        332       10    (50.0, 132.9, 382.0, 151.622)
32        332       10    (50.0, 118.5, 382.0, 137.222)
33    305.393       11  (64.0, 104.1, 369.393, 122.822)
34        318       12     (64.0, 89.7, 382.0, 108.422)
35        318       13      (64.0, 75.3, 382.0, 94.022)
36    319.165       13    (50.0, 60.9, 369.165, 79.622)
37    308.165       14    (64.0, 46.5, 372.165, 65.222)
38        318       15      (64.0, 32.1, 382.0, 50.822)
39    329.153       15    (50.0, 17.7, 379.153, 36.422)
40        318       16       (64.0, 3.3, 382.0, 22.022)
41    324.335       16    (50.0, -11.1, 374.335, 7.622)
```

**Code**:

```
parafix_df = main_df[["line_text", "line_width", "para_num", "bbox" ]]
parafix_df["new_para_num"] = 0

max_width = parafix_df['line_width'].max()
bbox_max_width = parafix_df.loc[selected['line_width'] == max_width].iloc[0]["bbox"]

previous = None
para1 = 1
for current, next in izip(parafix_df.iterrows(), parafix_df.iloc[1:].iterrows()):
    if previous==None:
        current[1]["new_para_num"] = para1
    else:
        bbox_current = current[1]["bbox"]
        bbox_next = next[1]["bbox"]
        bbox_previous = previous[1]["bbox"]
        if bbox_current[0]>bbox_max_width[0]:
            para1 += 1
            print "para1:", para1
        current[1]["new_para_num"] = para1

    previous = current
```

**Output of above code**:

```
                              bbox  new_para_num  
0   (50.0, 579.3, 288.546, 598.022)             0  
1     (64.0, 564.9, 382.0, 583.622)             0  
2     (50.0, 550.5, 382.0, 569.222)             0  
3     (50.0, 536.1, 382.0, 554.822)             0  
4   (50.0, 521.7, 378.977, 540.422)             0  
5     (64.0, 507.3, 382.0, 526.022)             0  
6     (50.0, 492.9, 382.0, 511.622)             0  
7     (50.0, 478.5, 382.0, 497.222)             0  
8     (50.0, 464.1, 382.0, 482.822)             0  
9     (50.0, 449.7, 382.0, 468.422)             0  
10   (50.0, 435.3, 109.04, 454.022)             0  
11  (64.0, 420.9, 368.007, 439.622)             0  
12    (64.0, 406.5, 382.0, 425.222)             0  
13    (50.0, 392.1, 382.0, 410.822)             0  
14    (50.0, 377.7, 382.0, 396.422)             0  
15    (50.0, 363.3, 382.0, 382.022)             0  
16   (50.0, 348.9, 93.252, 367.622)             0  
17    (64.0, 334.5, 382.0, 353.222)             0  
18    (50.0, 320.1, 382.0, 338.822)             0  
19    (50.0, 305.7, 382.0, 324.422)             0  
20    (50.0, 291.3, 382.0, 310.022)             0  
21    (50.0, 276.9, 382.0, 295.622)             0  
22   (50.0, 262.5, 367.02, 281.222)             0  
23    (64.0, 248.1, 382.0, 266.822)             0  
24    (50.0, 233.7, 382.0, 252.422)             0  
25   (50.0, 219.3, 97.014, 238.022)             0  
26    (64.0, 204.9, 382.0, 223.622)             0  
27  (50.0, 190.5, 366.723, 209.222)             0  
28    (64.0, 176.1, 382.0, 194.822)             0  
29  (50.0, 161.7, 376.766, 180.422)             0  
30    (64.0, 147.3, 382.0, 166.022)             0  
31    (50.0, 132.9, 382.0, 151.622)             0  
32    (50.0, 118.5, 382.0, 137.222)             0  
33  (64.0, 104.1, 369.393, 122.822)             0  
34     (64.0, 89.7, 382.0, 108.422)             0  
35      (64.0, 75.3, 382.0, 94.022)             0  
36    (50.0, 60.9, 369.165, 79.622)             0  
37    (64.0, 46.5, 372.165, 65.222)             0  
38      (64.0, 32.1, 382.0, 50.822)             0  
39    (50.0, 17.7, 379.153, 36.422)             0  
40       (64.0, 3.3, 382.0, 22.022)             0  
41    (50.0, -11.1, 374.335, 7.622)             0
```

**but I want new para values:**

```
para1: 2
para1: 3
para1: 4
para1: 5
para1: 6
para1: 7
para1: 8
para1: 9
para1: 10
para1: 11
para1: 12
para1: 13
para1: 14
para1: 15
para1: 16
```

Can you help me?

**Following is my final working code:**

```
parafix_df = main_df[["line_text", "line_width", "para_num", "bbox" ]]
parafix_df["new_para_num"] = 0

max_width = parafix_df['line_width'].max()
bbox_max_width = parafix_df.loc[selected['line_width'] == max_width].iloc[0]["bbox"]

para1 = 1
for indx, current in enumerate(parafix_df.iterrows(), start=0):
    if indx!=0:
        bbox_current = current[1]["bbox"]
        if bbox_current[0]>bbox_max_width[0]:
            para1 += 1
    parafix_df.iloc[indx, 4] = para1
```

can we optimized more?

Comment: in your code you are always accessing only the second row (with the index: `1`) - `current[1]`, `next[1]`. But i guess you don't need to loop through your DF in order to achieve your goals - it should be possible to do it in "pandas" way

Comment: yes, I am new in Pandas. Can u check my code again, I updated code.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

IIUC, you can do it this way:

```
df.new_para_num = 1

In [210]: df.loc[df.line_width == df.line_width.max(), 'new_para_num'].cumsum() + 1
Out[210]:
2      2
3      3
6      4
7      5
8      6
9      7
13     8
14     9
15    10
18    11
19    12
20    13
21    14
24    15
31    16
32    17
Name: new_para_num, dtype: int64
```

if you want to update `new_para_num` column in your original DF conditionally:

```
In [223]: df.new_para_num = 1

In [224]: selected = df.loc[df.line_width == df.line_width.max()].copy()

In [226]: selected.new_para_num = selected.new_para_num.cumsum() + 1

In [227]: selected
Out[227]:
    line_width  para_num                           bbox  new_para_num
2        332.0       2.0  [50.0, 550.5, 382.0, 569.222]             2
3        332.0       2.0  [50.0, 536.1, 382.0, 554.822]             3
6        332.0       3.0  [50.0, 492.9, 382.0, 511.622]             4
7        332.0       3.0  [50.0, 478.5, 382.0, 497.222]             5
8        332.0       3.0  [50.0, 464.1, 382.0, 482.822]             6
9        332.0       3.0  [50.0, 449.7, 382.0, 468.422]             7
13       332.0       5.0  [50.0, 392.1, 382.0, 410.822]             8
14       332.0       5.0  [50.0, 377.7, 382.0, 396.422]             9
15       332.0       5.0  [50.0, 363.3, 382.0, 382.022]            10
18       332.0       6.0  [50.0, 320.1, 382.0, 338.822]            11
19       332.0       6.0  [50.0, 305.7, 382.0, 324.422]            12
20       332.0       6.0  [50.0, 291.3, 382.0, 310.022]            13
21       332.0       6.0  [50.0, 276.9, 382.0, 295.622]            14
24       332.0       7.0  [50.0, 233.7, 382.0, 252.422]            15
31       332.0      10.0  [50.0, 132.9, 382.0, 151.622]            16
32       332.0      10.0  [50.0, 118.5, 382.0, 137.222]            17

In [228]: df.loc[df.line_width == df.line_width.max(), 'new_para_num'] = selected

In [229]: df
Out[229]:
    line_width  para_num                             bbox  new_para_num
0      238.546       NaN  [50.0, 579.3, 288.546, 598.022]             1
1      318.000       1.0    [64.0, 564.9, 382.0, 583.622]             1
2      332.000       2.0    [50.0, 550.5, 382.0, 569.222]             2
3      332.000       2.0    [50.0, 536.1, 382.0, 554.822]             3
4      328.977       2.0  [50.0, 521.7, 378.977, 540.422]             1
5      318.000       3.0    [64.0, 507.3, 382.0, 526.022]             1
6      332.000       3.0    [50.0, 492.9, 382.0, 511.622]             4
7      332.000       3.0    [50.0, 478.5, 382.0, 497.222]             5
8      332.000       3.0    [50.0, 464.1, 382.0, 482.822]             6
9      332.000       3.0    [50.0, 449.7, 382.0, 468.422]             7
10      59.040       3.0   [50.0, 435.3, 109.04, 454.022]             1
11     304.007       4.0  [64.0, 420.9, 368.007, 439.622]             1
12     318.000       5.0    [64.0, 406.5, 382.0, 425.222]             1
13     332.000       5.0    [50.0, 392.1, 382.0, 410.822]             8
14     332.000       5.0    [50.0, 377.7, 382.0, 396.422]             9
15     332.000       5.0    [50.0, 363.3, 382.0, 382.022]            10
16      43.252       5.0   [50.0, 348.9, 93.252, 367.622]             1
17     318.000       6.0    [64.0, 334.5, 382.0, 353.222]             1
18     332.000       6.0    [50.0, 320.1, 382.0, 338.822]            11
19     332.000       6.0    [50.0, 305.7, 382.0, 324.422]            12
20     332.000       6.0    [50.0, 291.3, 382.0, 310.022]            13
21     332.000       6.0    [50.0, 276.9, 382.0, 295.622]            14
22     317.020       6.0   [50.0, 262.5, 367.02, 281.222]             1
23     318.000       7.0    [64.0, 248.1, 382.0, 266.822]             1
24     332.000       7.0    [50.0, 233.7, 382.0, 252.422]            15
25      47.014       7.0   [50.0, 219.3, 97.014, 238.022]             1
26     318.000       8.0    [64.0, 204.9, 382.0, 223.622]             1
27     316.723       8.0  [50.0, 190.5, 366.723, 209.222]             1
28     318.000       9.0    [64.0, 176.1, 382.0, 194.822]             1
29     326.766       9.0  [50.0, 161.7, 376.766, 180.422]             1
30     318.000      10.0    [64.0, 147.3, 382.0, 166.022]             1
31     332.000      10.0    [50.0, 132.9, 382.0, 151.622]            16
32     332.000      10.0    [50.0, 118.5, 382.0, 137.222]            17
33     305.393      11.0  [64.0, 104.1, 369.393, 122.822]             1
34     318.000      12.0     [64.0, 89.7, 382.0, 108.422]             1
35     318.000      13.0      [64.0, 75.3, 382.0, 94.022]             1
36     319.165      13.0    [50.0, 60.9, 369.165, 79.622]             1
37     308.165      14.0    [64.0, 46.5, 372.165, 65.222]             1
38     318.000      15.0      [64.0, 32.1, 382.0, 50.822]             1
39     329.153      15.0    [50.0, 17.7, 379.153, 36.422]             1
40     318.000      16.0       [64.0, 3.3, 382.0, 22.022]             1
41     324.335      16.0    [50.0, -11.1, 374.335, 7.622]             1
```

PS but i'm still not sure that i understood correctly your goals

**OLD answer:**

you can use [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function in order to access previous and next rows:

```
df.shift(-1)  # df will be shifted one row backwards (will show `next` row) 

df.shift(1)  # df will be shifted one row forwards (will show `prev` row)
```

Example:

```
In [142]: df
Out[142]:
   a  b  c
0  8  3  0
1  8  3  4
2  9  4  1
3  2  1  8
4  5  6  3

In [147]: df['prev_a'] = df.a.shift(1)

In [148]: df['next_a'] = df.a.shift(-1)

In [149]: df
Out[149]:
   a  b  c  prev_a  next_a
0  8  3  0     NaN     8.0
1  8  3  4     8.0     9.0
2  9  4  1     8.0     2.0
3  2  1  8     9.0     5.0
4  5  6  3     2.0     NaN
```

Comment: thank you +10, but I can not reflect change in `new_para_num` column

Comment: @VivekSable, Could you please post sample _input_ and desired  _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format __as text__, so one could use it when coding) and describe what do you want to do with the input data in order to get output data set? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I want to assign value to new column according to logic. (logic i will update)

Comment: @VivekSable, could you also add a desired output for the first 5 rows (this should be enough) of the input data set - this will help to understand your logic much better?

Comment: Actual my logic in not correct, I just want to assign value in `new_para_num` to each row in `for` loop. I am getting `0` for all rows after running above code.

Comment: @VivekSable, i've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113049/discussion-between-maxu-and-vivek-sable).